# How to set a color for a rectangle?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, color

I had drawn a rectangle by adding *element* to *graphics container* like the code below:

```
IGraphicsContainer gc = mxDoc.FocusMap as IGraphicsContainer;
gc.Reset();
IRectangleElement rectangleElement = new RectangleElementClass();
IElement elem = rectangleElement as IElement;
gc.AddElement(elem, 0);
```

I want to remove the color from the rectangle or set the Transparency by 100, and keep the outline colored as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QI/cast from your rectangle element to [`IFillShapeElement`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00120000050m000000) and set its [`Symbol.Color`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Color_Property/001w0000015t000000/) property to [`IColor.NullColor`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/NullColor_Property/001w000000nq000000/).

Comment: thanks, i did it like this : IFillShapeElement fem = (IFillShapeElement)rectangleElement;
                        ISimpleFillSymbol fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbolClass();
                        fillSymbol.Style = esriSimpleFillStyle.esriSFSHollow;
                        fem.Symbol = fillSymbol;